# Should we re-do the verification in runtime call?

Tags: security, unsigned, transaction-pool

Imagine there is an unsigned extrinsic call.

```rs
#[pallet::call]
fn call(something, ..) -> DispatchResult {
    ensure_none()?;

    // verify(something)?;

    Ok(())
}

#[pallet::validate_unsigned]
impl .. {
    fn validate_unsigned(call, ..) {
        match call {
            call(something, ..) => verify(something),
            _ => return Err
        }

        return Ok
    }
}
```

We already do the verification in the `validate_unsigned`.

1. Should we?
   To my understanding, we should.
   If any validator/collator modifies their node to remove the `validate_unsigned` part. Then he could skip that.
2. Why? How will the extrinsic be executed and broadcast in the network in this case?

---

I found the Polkadot did the first verification here https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/d57049f1e4e5b00309cdd0297235a8de821f601d/runtime/common/src/claims.rs#L475.

And second here https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/d57049f1e4e5b00309cdd0297235a8de821f601d/runtime/common/src/claims.rs#L317.

Why the second one is necessary?

If we remove the second one. What would happen? How does the attacker make a successful attack in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to do the same checks while applying the unsigned extrinsic as in `validate_block`.

As you need to implement [`ValidateUnsigned`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/62a85fb07335b957ebb98434fdbd45232b732d85/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L1343-L1370) for your pallet, it will already do the verification while applying the unsigned extrinsic. This assumes that you don't change the default implementation of `pre_dispatch`. If you implement the method on your own, you need to ensure that `pre_dispatch` and `validate_unsigned` are doing exactly the same checks! I mean they can do different kind of checks, but validity should be checked in both implementations in the same way.

> Why the second one is necessary?

In the example you gave above the signer is extracted in `validate_unsigned` to check that it exists in `Claims`. This is done to prevent spam. As unsigned transaction are not paying any fees, you want to ensure that no one is spamming you with these transactions. So, your `validate_unsigned` logic should contain some code to reject these transactions early aka before they can enter the pool. However, as always in the context of `validate_transaction` (the context in that we call `validate_unsigned`) you should ensure that your checks are lightweight as otherwise you may make these checks a dos vector to your network.

Another point on why we need to call `eth_recover` in the implementation of the call again is that we can not pass data from `pre_dispatch` to the actual call dispatch.

Comment: If I don't perform the verification in the `#[pallet::call]`. I only do the verification in `#[pallet::validate_unsigned]`. What will happen? When the invalid extrinsic broadcast to other nodes' transaction pool, they will reject it I think. How does the attacker make a successful attack?

Comment: What attacker? What kind of attack? I don't get it. Did you read what I have written above? That the same checks as in `validate_unsigned` are also done in `pre_dispatch` as this calls to `validate_unsigned` in the default implementation.

Comment: Skip the transaction pool level verification. And make the invalid extrinsic successful. Because I don't verify it in runtime call. IIUC `validate_unsigned` only works for transaction pool verification which is off-chain.

Comment: Please take a look at this. If I remove these lines https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/d57049f1e4e5b00309cdd0297235a8de821f601d/runtime/common/src/claims.rs#L316-L319. Is that safe? We already did these verification in the `validate_unsigned`. Is that necessary?

Comment: I updated my comment above to include your extra questions. You can not remove these lines as the code would not work anymore.

Comment: > IIUC validate_unsigned only works for transaction pool verification which is off-chain.

You did not read on what I have written above from the beginning.

> As you need to implement ValidateUnsigned for your pallet, it will already do the verification while applying the unsigned extrinsic.

This works by having `pre_dispatch` call `validate_unsigned` in the default implementation of `pre_dispatch`.

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems I got lost in a dead loop before. So, if you provide a `signer` 
parameter field in the `claim` call and compare it with the `eth_recover` result in the `validate_unsigned`. Then we could safely skip the second verification.

Comment: Yes that should work!

Comment: Thanks again! So, the first question's answer is NO. We don't need to re-do the verification. I'll improve my question. Maybe it made you confuse.

Comment: No the answer is not really "no". The answer is that you should do the same checks while applying as in validation. Point being where you do these checks, if you just use `pre_validate` then you don't need to do it in your call again. However, you could also implement `pre_validate` omitting all checks.